# What is 1 * new Date()?

Tags: javascript, date, type-conversion

Reading through the jQuery source code and I have come across the following line of code:

```
1 * new Date()
```

Following a Google search, I have also seen that it is included in the Google Analytics snippet.

Can anyone explain what is happening here, and the purpose of this line?
Is it to generate a random number that will not be repeated again?

Comment: It looks like a very ugly way to write `Date.now()`. My guess: Backward compatibility with very old or bad browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did check it out, and saw what was returned. But I was hoping to find out the purpose of using this code, and how multiplying `1*Thu Mar 17 2016 09:38:52 GMT+0000 (GMT) gives you a 1458207532096`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new Date()` will return a `Date()` object. When coerced to a string the object returns an ISO formatted string interpretation of the date:

```
console.log(new Date()); // = 'Thu Mar 17 2016 09:37:12 GMT+0000 (GMT)'
```

When coerced to an integer this will then return the epoch timestamp of that date:

```
console.log(1 * new Date()); // = 1458207432249
```

Here's an example showing both outcomes:

```js
var d1 = new Date();
var d2 = 1 * new Date();

console.log(d1);
console.log(d2);
```

Note that the coercion to an int returns the same value as `Date.now()`, however [that method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) is not available in IE8 and older.

Comment: However, that line of code appears in jQuery versions higher than 2, which don't support IE 8 anyway. It seems to be shorthand for `new Date().getTime()`, but if brevity mattered (and really, it doesn't here), then `+new Date()` is shorter. Earlier versions use `-(new Date())` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

The part of code that you refer to is:

```
expando = "sizzle" + 1 * new Date(),
```

> Is it to generate a random number that will not be repeated again?

Not so much random as one that will not recur on the host (though it might if the clock is reset to an earlier date or the code is run again before the next clock tick, which might be 1 to 15 milliseconds later).

As noted in other answers, it's equivalent to `+new Date()` and `new Date().getTime()`.

#### However…

There is another use, which is for copying dates. Prior to ECMAScript 2015, given:

```
new Date(value)
```

if *value* was a Date object, then its *toString* method was called (see [*ES5 §15.9.3.2*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2), via a call to [*ToPrimitive*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1), which for Date objects calls *toString*, see the notes at the bottom of [*§8.12.8*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.8)), which generates an implementation dependent string. This is parsed to generate the new date. This had the quirk in some browsers where dates that genuinely had 2 digit years being converted to dates in the 20th century (e.g. a date for 21 May, 71 would become 21 May, 1971).

Using a modern Gregorian calendar for such dates isn't a good idea anyway, so likely it didn't bother too many people. This was fixed in ECMAScript 2015 so that where *value* is a Date, it's converted to a Number first, which returns the [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-time-values-and-time-range) (see [*§20.3.2.2 #3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-value)).

Of course it's only fixed in browsers that comply with the ECMAScript 2015 specification.

Firefox still seems to live in the past. Copying a date using `new Date(date)` loses the milliseconds, so it likely it's still using *toString* and not including the milliseconds (most browsers don't). So (in Firefox up to version 43.04, apparently [*fixed in version 44*](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1187233)), copying using `new Date(date)` in the following returns *false* but in ECMAScript 2015 compliant browsers (pretty much any other browser more modern than IE 8) it returns *true*:

```js
var x = new Date();
var y = new Date(x);
var z = new Date(+x);

document.write('Copy using <code>new Date(date)</code> keeps milliseconds: ' + (x.getTime() == y.getTime()));
document.write('<br>Copy using<code>new Date(+date)</code> keeps milliseconds: ' + (x.getTime() == z.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is Date to integer conversion:

```
var date = new Date();
//conversion by + sign (without white space)
console.log(+date); //123454545645645645

//conversion by multiply 1 
console.log(1*date); //123454545645645645

//get int value without conversion
console.log(date.getTime()); //123454545645645645
console.log(Date.now()); //123454545645645645
```